# Bertanlaffy growth - differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

Suppose a tumor of mass $m$ satisfies the differential equation $\frac{dm}{dt}=am^{\frac{3}{4}}-bm-cm^{\frac{2}{3}}$, where $c$ increases slowly from zero. Show that as $c$ increases, the tumour eventually completely disappears.

To do this, I tried sketching a graph of $\frac{dm}{dt}$ but this didn't really yield any results for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Let $m=u^{12}$ to make
$$12\,u'\,u^3+b\,u^4-a\,u=-c$$ Switch variables to get $t(u)$ and compute $\partial t/\partial c$ and analyze.

Comment: I don't understand this - could you perhaps explain how to use the graph to determine the result?

Comment: Have a look at https://vrs.amsi.org.au/wp-content/uploads/sites/78/2016/03/Sarah_Gazelle.pdf

Comment: @Alidixon244 You don't use graphs to determine a result like yours. You use calculus.